# Аналог абстрактных полей в Java

Tags: java, ооп, наследование

Есть абстрактный класс и в нем поле. Как в абстрактном классе добиться того, чтобы в классах наследниках мы были вынуждены задавать значение этого поля?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На мой взгляд способ самый очевидный - через параметры конструктора абстрактного класса:

```
abstract class Foo {

    private int var;

    Foo(int var) {
        this.var = var;
        System.out.println("var = " + var);
    }
}
```

И наследник:

```
class Bar extends Foo {

    Bar() {
        super(42);
    }
}
```

так же возможно объявлять методы абстрактными и использовать их в вашем классе:

```
abstract class Foo {

    Foo() {
        int var = getVar();
        System.out.println("var = " + var);
    }

    abstract int getVar();
}
```

тогда тому кто будет реализовывать этот класс будет придется реализовать и этот метод:

```
class Bar extends Foo {

    int getVar() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Для этого можете создать абстрактный метод.

```
void init()
{
    System.out.println(getName());
}

protected abstract String getName();
```